# Chained DropDown for Countries->States->City

Tags: html, state, country, city, datafeed

I know there are a lot of questions asked regarding this. But most answers/workarounds are pretty old to work with.

I tried the GeoName and some more options but was not satisfied.

Have we found any way to get the updated/recent **(not hardcoded)** list of countries, states, and cities in a simple manner so that we can get a dynamic dropdown with it?
If we have, can I please get the link to the article/doc/blog/something?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is pretty generic and it is not relevant with the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any dev searching something similar, I found [this](https://geodata.solutions/) which is just similar but pretty compact version of Geonames.
Will keep posting here if I find something more useful and handy.